# Check chars in a string while using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to check each individual char in a string. The string is stored in a pointer.
for some reason I can't, it only let me get the whole string.
here's my code:

```
int main() {
  char *s=(char*)calloc(30,sizeof(char));
  s="hello";
  printf("%s",&s[2]);
  return 0;
 }
```

this code print "llo", i need only 1 char like "l" or "o".
anyone know how i can achieve it?
ty

Comment: Printf characters not strings.  Look up the formatting codes for printf, and ask yourself what is the value of s[2] if you leave off the '&'.

Comment: you also lost the block you created with `calloc` (memory leak). What do you mean by *check each individual char* ?

Comment: `printf("%c",s[2]);`

Comment: try doing strcpy instead, setting s to point to "hello" is not the same thing as copying the string.

Comment: check each individual char, i mean like if i want to find the letter "l" or check if all the string is numbers only or none numbers string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%c` conversion specifier to print a sinlge `char`acter instead of `%s` to print a *string*.

Also the memory allocation by `calloc()` is useless, since the pointer to `char` `s` get assigned by the address of the first element of the string literal `"hello"` one statement later.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
    const char *s = "hello";
    printf("%c", s[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
l
```

Side Note:

- Use the `const` qualifier to prevent any unintentional write attempts to the string literal that lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

If you want to allocate memory and assign/initialize the allocated memory by the string literal `"hello"`, use `strcpy()` (header `string.h`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) 
{
    char *s = calloc(30, sizeof(*s));
    if (!s)      // Check if allocation failed.
    {
        fputs("Error at allocating memory!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(s, "hello");
    printf("%c", s[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
l
```

or you can use `strdup()` (Note: `strdup()` is not part of the standard C library) which will automatically allocate memory with the string of the string literal passed as argument initialized:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) 
{
    char *s = strdup("hello");
    if (!s)            // Check if allocation failed.
    {
        fputs("Error at allocating memory!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%c", s[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Side note:

> "The string is stored in a pointer."

Something like that is not possible. The pointer points to the first element of the string (literal). The pointer does not store a string.

Comment: or even strdup("Hello")

Comment: @pm100 Problem is that `strdup()` isn't part of the standard. I'm also not sure whether OP only allocates the memory for the string literal `"hello"`. Then s/he would not allocate an buffer of `30` `char` elements and only of `6` `char`'s. Quite mysterious code, tough.

Comment: strdup is posix standard

Comment: @pm100 Took it into the answer. Thanks. Was also a little absent before. OP can of course `realloc()` the malloc if needed.